# Como passar propriedades de outro model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

**Problema:** Tenho um index que utilizo um model do tipo:

```
    @model IEnumerable<projeto.Models.classe1>
```

Preciso acessar algumas propriedades da `classe 2`, a minha `classe1` sendo IEnumerable, como posso acessar as propriedades da `classe 2`?

Tentei passar: `Classe1 classe1 {get; set;}`.

Porém quando chamo o campo `model.classe1.NomeCampo` ele não deixa porque essa página utiliza o tipo IEnumerable da `classe 1`.

**Cenário Ideal:** Gostaria de acessar essa `classe 2` através do model `classe 1`.

Comment: inclua o seu código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tuas classes se relacionam?
Você pode criar uma ViewModel que contemple as tuas Models. Dentro da controller você trata o carregamento dessa ViewModel fazendo o mapeamento devido das tuas models para a ViewModel. Por Exemplo, digamos que tu queira exibir uma lista de de duas classes. A tua viewModel teria de ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
public class ClasseViewModel
{
    public Classe1 classe1 { get; set; }
    public Classe2 classe2 { get; set; }
}
```

Na View tu acessaria assim:

```
@model IEnumerable<projeto.ViewModel.ClasseViewModel>
```

Você pode tratar como quiser, colocando dentro um IEnumerable:

```
public class ClasseViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Classe1> classe1 { get; set; }
    public Classe2 classe2 { get; set; }
}
```

Na View Acessa da mesma forma:

```
@model IEnumerable<projeto.ViewModel.ClasseViewModel>
```

Porém nesse caso para acessar os dados da Classe1, tu tera de realizar um @foreach no razor para ler todos os itens do teu IEnumerable:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.classe1){
   @Html.Raw(item.atributo);
}
```