# Como chamo duas model em uma mesma view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, asp.net, aplicação-web, viewmodel

Bom dia pessoas, sou novo no asp então meu conhecimento é bem baixo, poderiam me ajudar com essa questão? eu tenho uma view para consulta que já possui uma model "LIVRO", e nessa mesma view eu pretendo deixar um dropdown para login, porém para isso necessito que a model "USUARIOS" chegue nessa view, poderiam por favor me dar um exemplo, para que eu possa entender? segue códigos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CSHTML:**

```html
@model IEnumerable<Repasse.Models.LIVRO>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <title>Repasse - Cadastros de Alunos</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/img/icone.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/content/webfonts/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/content/webfonts/fontawesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/content/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/content/css/livro/consultalivrohome.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!--SEÇÃO DO CABEÇALHO-->
    <header>
        <!-- 001 - NOmE E ICONE DO PROJETO NO NAVBAR -->
        <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #033157;">
            <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: #b5b5b5;"><span class="fas fa-books" style="color: #b5b5b5;"></span> Repasse</a>
            <!-- 001 - FIM -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Início</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="@Url.Action("Consultar", "Home")">Consultar Livros</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#"><i class="fa fa-user-o"></i> Entrar</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>
                                <form class="form-inline login-form" method="post">
                                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i></span>
                                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.USUARIO, new { id = "first-name", @class = "form-control", type = "text", name = "username", placeholder = "Usuário" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.USUARIO, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
                                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.SENHA, new { @class = "form-control", type = "password", name = "pass", placeholder = "Senha" })
                                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SENHA, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Entrar</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                            @*@{ if (ViewBag.Erro != null)
                                    {
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show btn-block" role="alert">
                                            <h6 style="color:red">@ViewBag.erro</h6>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                }*@
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--SEÇÃO DO CORPO-->
    <section class="corpo">
        <div class="buscartitulo">
            <section id="buscaraluno" class="search-sec">
                <h4 class="text-center mt-4"><i class="fas fa-print-search"></i> CONSULTAR LIVRO</h4>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table-wrapper">
                <div class="tabela-container">
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>COD.LIVRO</th>
                                <th>NUM.TOMBO</th>
                                <th>COD.ISBN</th>
                                <th>TITULO</th>
                                <th>ANO</th>
                                <th>EDIÇÃO</th>
                                <th>EDITORA</th>
                                <th>SITUAÇÃO</th>
                                <th>CATEGORIA.LIVRO</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COD_LIVRO)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NUM_TOMBO)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.COD_ISBN)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TITULO)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ANO)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EDICAO)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SITUACAO)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CATEGORIA_LIVRO)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EDITORA)</td>

                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--SEÇÃO DO RODAPÉ-->
    <footer>
        <nav id="rodape" class="navbar sticky-top">
            <a class="navbar-brand">
                <p class="textorodape">Copyright &copy; Hello Word - Repasse | ITB - Instituto Técnico de Barueri - Brasílio Flores de Azevedo</p>
            </a>
        </nav>
    </footer>

    <!--SEÇÃO DO JAVASCRIPT-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#datatable').DataTable({
                "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller:**

```html
using Repasse.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Repasse.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(USUARIOS log)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var db = new DBREPASSEEntities())
                {
                    var v = db.USUARIOS.Where(a => a.USUARIO.Equals(log.USUARIO) && a.SENHA.Equals(log.SENHA)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {

                        Session["nomeUsuarioLogado"] = v.NOME_USUARIO.ToString();
                        Session["telefoneUsuarioLogado"] = v.FONE_USUARIO.ToString();
                        Session["cpfUsuarioLogado"] = v.CPF_USUARIO.ToString();
                        Session["emailUsuarioLogado"] = v.EMAIL_USUARIO.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("Inicio", "Bibliotecario");
                    }
                    else ViewBag.Erro = "Campo senha ou usuário inválido!";
                }
            }
            return View();

        }

        public ActionResult Consultar()
        {
            DBREPASSEEntities db = new DBREPASSEEntities(); // Aqui coloca sua conexão com o banco de dados
            List<LIVRO> listaaluno = db.LIVRO.Where(x => x.STATUS_DEL == "I").OrderBy(x => x.TITULO).ToList<LIVRO>();

            return View(listaaluno);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Consultar(USUARIOS log)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var db = new DBREPASSEEntities())
                {
                    var v = db.USUARIOS.Where(a => a.USUARIO.Equals(log.USUARIO) && a.SENHA.Equals(log.SENHA)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (v != null)
                    {

                        Session["nomeUsuarioLogado"] = v.NOME_USUARIO.ToString();
                        Session["telefoneUsuarioLogado"] = v.FONE_USUARIO.ToString();
                        Session["cpfUsuarioLogado"] = v.CPF_USUARIO.ToString();
                        Session["emailUsuarioLogado"] = v.EMAIL_USUARIO.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("Inicio", "Bibliotecario");
                    }
                    else ViewBag.Erro = "Campo senha ou usuário inválido!";


                }

            }
            return View();

        }

        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

**MODEL USUARIOS:**

```html
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Repasse.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class USUARIOS
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public USUARIOS()
        {
            this.EMPRESTIMO = new HashSet<EMPRESTIMO>();
        }
    
        public int COD_USUARIO { get; set; }
        public string NOME_USUARIO { get; set; }
        public string FONE_USUARIO { get; set; }
        public string EMAIL_USUARIO { get; set; }
        public string SEXO_USUARIO { get; set; }
        public string CPF_USUARIO { get; set; }
        public string USUARIO { get; set; }
        public string PERFIL { get; set; }
        public string SENHA { get; set; }
        public string CONFIRMARSENHA { get; set; }
        public string STATUS_DEL { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<EMPRESTIMO> EMPRESTIMO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**MODEL LIVRO:**

```html
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Repasse.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class LIVRO
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public LIVRO()
        {
            this.AUTORIA = new HashSet<AUTORIA>();
            this.AUTORIA1 = new HashSet<AUTORIA>();
            this.ITENS_EMPRESTIMO = new HashSet<ITENS_EMPRESTIMO>();
        }
    
        public int COD_LIVRO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NUM_TOMBO { get; set; }
        public string COD_ISBN { get; set; }
        public string TITULO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ANO { get; set; }
        public string EDICAO { get; set; }
        public string SITUACAO { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> COD_CATEG { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> COD_EDITORA { get; set; }
        public string STATUS_DEL { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AUTORIA> AUTORIA { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AUTORIA> AUTORIA1 { get; set; }
        public virtual CATEGORIA_LIVRO CATEGORIA_LIVRO { get; set; }
        public virtual EDITORA EDITORA { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ITENS_EMPRESTIMO> ITENS_EMPRESTIMO { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: verifica se esse post te ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/400746/como-passar-propriedades-de-outro-model/400773#400773

Comment: Cara, te dei um ponto na pergunta pra tirar do negativo, agora vou responder pra você...

Answer (score 1):

Podes passar o modelo por `ViewData[""]`, por exemplo.

**Mas** do modo que tens essa aplicação não estás a utilizar toda a potencialidade da arquitetura .NET MVC.

Deverias criar um `Layout` que é transversal a todas as páginas na aplicação num só ficheiro, [exemplo](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2), e utilizar o `RenderBody()` para apresentar as diversas páginas (lista de usuários, lista de livros, criação usuários, etc.).

Também deverias isolar essa secção do login numa `PartialView` que tornaria a tua dúvida inexistente.

Se criares um projeto de raiz com o Visual Studio terás tudo isso já feito e que aconselho a estudar e experimentar um pouco.

Answer (score 1):

Você disse que tem uma view para consultar livros e tem uma model "LIVRO".
Isso significa que tua "model" livro é referente a teu banco de dados, LIVRO também deve ser sua tabela. Então, a tua model é sua tabela de banco de dados.

Acontece que no MVC, geralmente o pessoal manda a "model" (estrutura de dados) diretamente para view. Alguns tem a visão que a model é o próprio banco de dados.

No entanto, o teu requisito é que a tua view congregue informações de models diferente. LIVRO E USUÁRIO. Por isso, talvez a model que sua VIEW precise deva ser um DTO (data transfer object). Ou seja, um objeto, que tem a estrutura de dados de apresentação, que vai atender as necessidades de visualização de dados da tua VIEW e que vai agregar valores de estruturas diferentes do bancos de dados.

Ou seja, tua DTO deveria ser algo como:

```
public class HomeItemDTO
{
  public string CodigoLivro {get; set;}
  public string NumeroTumbo {get; set;}
  public string CodigoISBN {get; set;}
  public string Titulo {get; set;}
  public string Ano {get; set;}
  public string Edicao {get; set;}
  public string Editor {get; set;}
  public string Situação {get; set;}
  public string CategoriaLivro {get; set;}
}
```

Ai você pode criar um SQL que junta as duas tabelas e já popula informações diferentes nessa DTO ou você pode transmutar os resultados dos repositórios de Usuários e Livros nesse objeto DTO.